# Customize sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl

Tags: java, ssl, tls1.2, tls1.3

I would like modify sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl and use the customized class, for learning purposes.
I can't extend it - the class is final.
I can't copy/paste, because it uses several sun.security.ssl classes that can't be imported.
Are there any ideas?
A dirty way would be also ok - it's just for learning and playing.